# How can i fix my *ngfor , the footer is ignoring it and overlapsing the contents

Tags: html, css

[image]

the item contents are in *ngfor

i tried this css, it is going well if i make the body min height to 100vh, but when i turn it to mobile view,the ng content is floating in the middle.

```css
#body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
}
```

Comment: Could you share your HTML and enough code to reproduce the problem